# preg_replace_callback with array

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I recently updated my site to PHP 5.6, and since doing that, I started getting errors with the `e` modifier.

Here is the function causing the issue:

```
function blockPrepareDisplay() {
static $search = array('/(.)@(.)/se');
static $replace = array('"&#" .sprintf("%03d", ord("\\1")) .";&#064;&#" .sprintf("%03d", ord("\\2")) . ";";');
$resarray = array();
foreach (func_get_args() as $var) {
    $var = htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES);// Prepare var
    $var = preg_replace($search, $replace, $var);
    $var = preg_replace('/&amp;#/', '&#', $var);
    $var = str_replace("&amp;nbsp;","&nbsp;",$var);
    $var = str_replace("&amp;amp;","&amp;",$var);
    $resarray[] = $var;// Add to array
}
if (func_num_args() == 1) {// Return vars
    return $resarray[0];
} else {
    return $resarray;
  }
}
```

I understand that the line static `$search = array('/(.)@(.)/se');` is the line with the `e` modifier and I know that its deprecated. A friend explained that to me, and explained that I wound need to replace the `preg_replace` with a `preg_replace_callback`. I have looked over at php.net and all over here, but I think it made me more confuesd than ever.

I have tried for a couple of weeks now many different things and I got one to stop spitting the error, but I am positive that its wrong, and I prefer it to be right than wrong. I did this in replacement of the preg_replace

```
$var = preg_replace_callback(
$search,
function($replace){
    foreach($replace as $replaces){
        return $replaces;
    }
}, 
$var
);
```

Instead of the `$var = preg_replace($search, $replace, $var);`.
I also did remove the e modifier. Can anyone point out my mistake and give an example of how I should have this to be right?

Answer (score 0):

The argument of the callback function is the array of matching groups.

I don't understand why you are using an array for the search and the replacement parts, I'd do:

```
$var = "abc@def.org";

$var = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(.)@(.)/',
        function($match) {
            return sprintf("&#%03d;&#064;&#%03d;", ord($match[1]), ord($match[2]));
        },
        $var
    );
echo $var,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
ab&#099;&#064;&#100;ef.org
```